# Globally installed npm package not accessible in terminal

Tags: node.js, terminal, npm, protractor, npm-install

I installed `protractor` through `npm install -g protractor` which run successfully.

Running `npm -g ls --depth=0` shows `protractor` installed correctly.

```
azim@azim-desktop:~$ npm -g ls --depth=0
/home/azim/npm-global/lib
├── express-generator@4.13.1
├── generator-angular@0.12.1
├── generator-chrome-extension@0.3.1
├── generator-gulp-angular@1.0.2
├── generator-gulp-angular-subtask@0.9.1
├── generator-karma@1.0.0
├── generator-mocha@0.1.8
├── generator-react-webpack@3.2.2
├── git-remote-mango@0.0.2
├── jshint@2.7.0
├── jsx@0.9.89
├── mango-admin@0.1.1
├── n@2.1.0
├── npm@3.7.2
├── protractor@4.0.0
└── yo@1.6.0
```

but protractor isn't accessible in terminal.

```
azim@azim-desktop:~$ protractor
protractor: command not found
```

It was working fine a while ago, I've updated my `npm` and `node` to latest versions. I think after that the `PATH` variables messed up. Googled for a solution but didn't work anything. I don't want to mess up the current situation.

Current path is:

```
azim@azim-desktop:~$ echo $NODE_PATH
/usr/lib/nodejs:/usr/lib/node_modules:/usr/share/javascript:/home/azim/npm-global/lib/node_modules
```

Versions:

```
azim@azim-desktop:~$ npm --version
2.14.12
azim@azim-desktop:~$ node --version
v4.3.1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The environment variable `$NODE_PATH` is used by node to look for modules only.

Essentially you'll want to make sure that the directory path, where the `protractor` binary is located, is accessible through the environment variable `$PATH` instead.

**Example of where my protractor is installed:**

> root@codeblog:~# which protractor 
> **/usr/bin/protractor**
>   root@codeblog:~# env | grep PATH
>   
>   PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:**/usr/bin**:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
>   NODE_PATH=/usr/lib/nodejs:/usr/lib/node_modules:/usr/share/javascript

If you got `protractor` installed at another place then you might want to  tweak your `~/.bashrc` to append that directory into the `$PATH` variable.

**Like:**

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/my_protractor_dir/bin
```

Comment: Thanks. Added path to protractor in `PATH`. Like `PATH=$PATH:/home/azim/npm-global/lib/node_modules/protractor/bin` and it works.